# Get data from remote server for calendar events

Tags: sencha-touch

I have created a store:

```
Ext.regStore('EventCalendarStore',{
model: 'EventCalendar',
proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    url:url,
    reader:{
        type:'json'
    }
},
    autoLoad:true
});

EventsApp.stores.eventCalendarStore = Ext.StoreMgr.get('EventCalendarStore');
```

It stores data in json format.

I'm using Ext.ux.TouchCalendarView calendar, and this calendar recieves data in different way than from my created store structure.

```
var eventStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'Event',
    data: [{
        event: 'Breaking Development 2011',
        location: 'Nashville',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 12),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 14)
    }, {
        event: 'TechCrunch Disrupt SF',
        location: 'San Francisco',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 12),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 14)
    }, {
        event: 'ATypl Reykjavik 2011',
        location: 'Reykjavik',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 14),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 18)
    }, {
        event: 'Do Wales 2011',
        location: 'Cardigan',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 14),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 18)
    }, {
        event: 'Future of Mobile',
        location: 'London',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 16),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 16)
    }, {
        event: 'WindyCityRails 2011',
        location: 'Chicago',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 17),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 17)
    }, {
        event: 'CapitoUS',
        location: 'Washington DC',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 18),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 18)
    }, {
        event: 'Strange Loop 2011',
        location: 'St Louis',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 18),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 20)
    }, {
        event: 'Frozen Rails 2011',
        location: 'Helsinki',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 20),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 21)
    }, {
        event: 'Web Accessibility',
        location: 'London',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 21),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 21)
    }, {
        event: 'onGameStart',
        location: 'Warsaw',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 22),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 23)
    }, {
        event: 'Improving Reality',
        location: 'Brighton',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 23),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 23)
    }, {
        event: 'Android Homecoming',
        location: 'Mountain View',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 23),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 25)
    }, {
        event: 'Mobilize',
        location: 'San Francisco',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 26),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 27)
    }, {
        event: 'Accessibility Summit',
        location: 'Online',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 27),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 27)
    }, {
        event: 'UX Web Summit',
        location: 'Online',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 28),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 28)
    }, {
        event: 'Modernizer with Faruk Ates',
        location: 'San Francisco',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 29),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 29)
    }, {
        event: 'Creative JavaScript and HTML5',
        location: 'Brighton',
        start: new Date(2011, 8, 29),
        end: new Date(2011, 8, 30)
    }, {
        event: 'UX Camp Brighton',
        location: 'Brighton',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 1),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 1)
    }, {
        event: 'Future of Web Apps',
        location: 'London',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 3),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 5)
    }, {
        event: 'droidcon 2011',
        location: 'London',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 6),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 7)
    }, {
        event: 'PHP NW 2011',
        location: 'Manchester',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 7),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 9)
    }, {
        event: 'O\'Reilly Android Open Conference',
        location: 'San Francisco',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 9),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 11)
    }, {
        event: 'Web 2.0 Expo/NY',
        location: 'New York',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 10),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 13)
    }, {
        event: 'Sencha Con',
        location: 'Austin, Texas',
        start: new Date(2011, 9, 23),
        end: new Date(2011, 9, 26)
    }, {
        event: 'Future of Web Design',
        location: 'New York',
        start: new Date(2011, 10, 7),
        end: new Date(2011, 10, 9)
    }, {
        event: 'Build',
        location: 'Belfast',
        start: new Date(2011, 10, 7),
        end: new Date(2011, 10, 11)
    }, {
        event: 'Heart &amp; Sole',
        location: 'Portsmouth',
        start: new Date(2011, 10, 18),
        end: new Date(2011, 10, 18)
    }]
});
```

That's why I have to create another store for this calendar, and render the format in the proper way. I'm recreating the store like this way:

```
EventsApp.stores.eventCalendarStore.load(function(){
    EventsApp.stores.eventCalendarStore.each(function(record){

        var dateS = record.data.startTime;
        var dateE = record.data.endTime;

        var converterEndTime = new Date();
        var converterStartTime = new Date();
        var startT = new Object();
        var endT = new Object();

        if(typeof dateS =='string') {
            converterStartTime = new Date(dateS.substr(0,10)*1000);

        }else {
            converterStartTime = new Date(dateS);
        }


        if(typeof dateE =='string'){
            converterEndTime = new Date(dateE.substr(0,10)*1000);
        }else{
            converterEndTime = new Date(dateE);
        }
        endT = converterEndTime.format("Y , n, j");
        startT = converterStartTime.format("Y , n, j");
        var cStore = EventsApp.stores.eventCalendarOfflineStore;
        cStore.add({
            event:record.data.name,
            location:record.data.notes,
            start:new Date(startT),
            end:new Date(endT)
        });
        cStore.sync();
        record.save();
    });
});
```

But the data is not transfering from the first store to the second.

How can I transfer data to the second store? or are there any ways for giving the data from the first store to the calendar in other way?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never. To answer your question, you can make use of HTTP caching and load the store in the second store's init function. since it has been cached the data is there for you without network transport.